# Integrating html pages designed in dreamweaver to visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dreamweaver

Hi I am supposed to design a complete website and use .net for doing so. I used dreamweaver to design/create all the web pages. Now I am trying to load them to visual studio by just changing the extension from .html to .aspx to create c# code for those pages. These are problems I am having:

1. Double clicking on buttons/textboxes is not opening the .cs page. Infact I am not having any .cs page created for these pages.

what changes should I make to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="page_name.aspx.cs" %>` and create cs file names `page_name.aspx.cs` and page class in it, but there is a easier way to do that.

Just create new aspx file in Visual Studio, and replace its content with your html content. Don't remove top line of aspx file.

Note: You should create aspx files in Visual Studio anyway. Probably you will have to change your button, input, or any other form controls to aspx controls. So there is a lots of work to do.